# Continuous $n$-th order derivative

Tags: calculus

Does a continuous $n$-th order derivative imply that all previous order derivatives are also continuous? I intuitively believe this is the case, but I can't entirely convince myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mere existence of the $n$'th derivative implies that all previous derivatives are differentiable, hence continuous.